# How do you get the parent control from an event send by a control in the resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I defined a context menu in the resources of a Datarid. In the Click event of the context menu I want to check the name of the parent control (DataGrid). I tried VisualTreeHelper.GetParent() and LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent() but neither reflects the hierarchy in the xaml. How do I get the DataGrid Control from the Click event? Thanks for your answers.

Code:

```
private void datagridTargetDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check the name of the DataGrid here...
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="datagridTarget">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="DGTContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="datagridTargetDelete_Click">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="{Binding ContextDeleteIcon}"/>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image ContextMenu="{DynamicResource DGTContextMenu}" Height="16" Width="16" Source="{Binding ObjectImage}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider a RoutedCommand with a CommandBinding on the parent element in this case. This is actually how ContextMenu is supposed to be used, I think. That way, WPF would find the parent object for you, you wouldn't have to search the logical tree for it.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the exact Thing you want:

```
var parent = ((ContextMenu)((MenuItem)sender).Parent).PlacementTarget;
```