# How to navigate to a xaml page from ResourceDictionary class (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary, navigationservice

I have a ResourceDictionary class as follows:

```js
  using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using static myApp.filesXAML.Login;

    namespace myApp.Clases
    {
        partial class functionsMenu : ResourceDictionary
        {
            private void imageCloseMyApp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("filesXAML/Login.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
        }
    }
```

The imageCloseMyApp function is invoked from an image by clicking on it and I wish to call another page.

And I get the following error before compiling the project:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Status deleted Error
CS0120 An object reference is required for the field, method or
property 'NavigationService.Navigate (Uri)' not static myApp
H:\pro\Visual_Studio\myApp\myApp\Classes\ FunctionsMenu.cs 35 Active

I have searched the internet, and tried the following options:

```js
Login page = new Login();         
page.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("filesXAML/Login.xaml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

// or

NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(Application.Current.Windows[0].Parent);
nav.Navigate(new Uri("filesXAML/Login.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

But none works.

Any suggestions or comments?

Comment: What `NavigationService` are you trying to use for navigation? Is there even a `Frame` somewhere in your application?

Comment: It's a Page. Thanks for writing

Comment: What is a `Page`?

Comment: It's MainPage constructor

Comment: I don't understand. Please edit your question and include all details. Your current question doesn't make much sense. There is no `NavigationService` set up in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved it as follows:

```js
 NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService((Grid)((Image)sender).Parent);
nav.Navigate(new Uri("filesXAML/Login.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

I guide myself to understand the following thread:

[How do you get the parent control from an event send by a control in the resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640610/how-do-you-get-the-parent-control-from-an-event-send-by-a-control-in-the-resourc)